# cant create handler app crashes on first launch

Tags: java, android, webview

Using webview app template everything is fine, but just app keeps crashing on the first launch, I can't create a handler by java error, if someone could kindly help me please

```js
FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-4-thread-1
Process: com.brommko.android.tasweqo, PID: 9676
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
 at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
 at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
 at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:345)
 at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:101)
 at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:259)
 at com.brommko.android.tasweqo.firebase.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.sendRegistrationToServer(MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java:46)
 at com.brommko.android.tasweqo.firebase.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.onTokenRefresh(MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java:31)
 at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zza(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zzm(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb$2.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Please show the [MCVE] that demonstrates this.

Answer (score 0):

```
at com.brommko.android.tasweqo.firebase.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.sendRegistrationToServer(MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java:46)
```

May be in the sub-thread to update the operation of the page，android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:259)